# Is there an easy way to stop and reissue a command?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal, node.js

I am doing Node.js development in Ubuntu and I'm curious if there is a way to quickly stop and restart a node server.

I run this command to start my app:

> $ node app.js

When I make changes to app.js I have to restart the server.
To stop it I have to use CTRL-C followed by UP and then <kbd>enter</kbd> to reissue the startup command.

Is there a faster way to do this? It doesn't seem like much until you're making many minor changes and needing to restart a lot.

Comment: 3 keystrokes is too much work?

Comment: Nice straw man, but I didn't make that statement. I simply asked if there was a quicker way.

Answer (score 3):

run it in cycle:

```
while : ; do node app.js ; done
```

so every time you'll hit CTRL-C it will end current node and start next one itself.

To end cycle just hold CTRL-C a while or kill from another shell or even close shell session.

Comment: This only works if SIGINT is trapped by the shell, which is not the case by default.   Try it.

Comment: I tried it many times. It doesn't work with `sleep` or `echo`, but it does work with smth like `ssh -N` and `node`.

Answer (score 0):

Many servers accept `SIGHUP` as a signal to reload their configuration.   But if this will not work for you a simple alternative is to use Control-O instead of return.   That executes this command and then fetches the next command from the history.   Try it like this:

```
echo hello
echo world
[cursor-up twice]
[now press control-O until you get bored]
```

Works on Bash, I forget how widespread this feature is.

In this case for running `node` repeatedly you would just alternate Control-C and Control-O.

Comment: It will not work, cause u need to stop command at first (`node` doesn't end itself like `echo` in your example).

Comment: That's why the instructions above mention that you need to press Control-C.